# how to convert list to IEnumerable<string>?

Tags: c#, append, filestream

> **Error** CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task SerializeAsync(List<ProgrammInfo> list)
{
    using (FileStream fs = File.AppendAllLines("save3.json", list))
    {
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            WriteIndented = true
        };
        await JsonSerializer.SerializeAsync(fs, list, options);
    }
}
```

Comment: list(ofObject)  basically is an IEnumerable(ofObject). This should not cause any problem. Could you please post the inner exception here?

Comment: the 2nd parameter of method [File.AppendAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalllines?view=netframework-4.8) is IEnumerable<string>, your input List<ProgrammInfo> cannot be converted to IEnumerable<string> implicitly

Comment: There seem to be multiple problems here. But you've not given enough information to give a complete answer. What are you trying to achieve exactly? (looks like an attempt to write your `List<ProgramInfo> list` as json to a file?). As said above `File.AppendAllLines` requires an `IEnumerable<string>` also `File.AppendAllLines` doesn't return a `FileStream` so that won't work either (it returns `void`). Something like this might help: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeWithJsonSerializerToFile.htm

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the variable list is not a list of strings but a list of ProgramInfo. By using Linq You can change the code like this:

```
        public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task SerializeAsync(List<ProgrammInfo> list)
        {

            var stringList = list.Select(x => x.ToString());

            using (FileStream fs = File.AppendAllLines("save3.json", stringList))
...
```

But I could not make the code run since AppendAllLines return void ...  and to serialize an object to json and write it to a file can be done easier as Knoop commented.